# Twig, PHP Count quantity of daily client events from MySql DB

Tags: php, mysql, twig

I am trying to retrieve to total daily quantity COUNT of daily events from within my DB.

DB array

```
    Array
    (
        [id] => 355
        [title] => Tandem Jump
        [qty] => 2
        [start] => 2016-12-17 00:00:00
    )

    (
        [id] => 356
        [title] => Tandem Jump
        [qty] => 3
        [start] => 2016-12-17 00:00:00
    )
```

My `Controller` has the following `function()`

```
    public function countDailyTandems() {
        $orders = Calendar::where('title', 'Tandem Jump')->where('qty', '>=', 1)->whereDate('start', '=', Carbon::today())->get();

        $ids = [];

        foreach($orders as $order) {
            $ids[] = $order->id;
        }

        $id = Calendar::find($ids);

        foreach($id as $item) {
            $qty = $item->qty;
        }

        return $qty;
    }
```

So, i am trying to get the total count, for example `5` from the above `array` but it is only picking up the first record.

My view is rendered with `Twig` as follows

```
{{ count.countDailyTandems() }}
```

Any help would be greatly accepted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around what seemed like forever, i have a solution that works just in case anyone needs a simular

```
$orders = Calendar::where('title', 'Tandem Jump')->where('qty', '>=', 1)->whereDate('start', '=', Carbon::today())->get();

    $ids = [];
    $qty = null;

    foreach($orders as $order) {
        $ids[] = $order->id;
    }

    $id = Calendar::find($ids);

    foreach($id as $item => $value) {
        $qty += $id[$item]['qty'];
    }

    if(!$qty) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $qty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having that function within your controller, have you tried using the SQL's SUM function like so?

```
$sum = Calendar::select(DB::raw('SUM(qty)'))
        ->where('qty', '>=', 1)
        ->whereDate('start', Carbon::today())
        ->first();
```

Once you have passed $sum through to your view, it'd be as simple as calling `{{ sum }}`

Comment: Hi @homemadejam i am using `Eloquent` for my DB connection. Also your suggestion is only bring the `first()` record. I am trying to get the total count of BOTH records. I have in this example `2` records with a `qty` total of `5`

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding you here.
The DB finds the SUM of all the quantities where it's greater than or equal to one. So the DB is doing the maths for you, and it simply returns one result - that being the SUM of all the specified quantities. This therefore means there's no reason to have to return the quantities of all the records that match your criteria to only then add them up.